# identifying which jpa mapping between customer and currentPaymentMethod

Tags: java, jpa, payment

I have written a Customer class which has two fields.A `Set<Payment> payments` and a `selectedPayment` .A customer can have many credit cards and can select one of them for current purchase.The various credit cards are modelled by the payments field.

```
@Entity
class Customer{
  ...
  @OneToMany( cascade=CascadeType.ALL,orphanRemoval=true)
  Set<Payment> payments;
  @OneToOne( cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
  Payment selectedPayment;

}

@Entity
class Payment{
   String creditCardNumber;
   String creditCardType;
   ...
}
```

Are these the correct mappings? In the db table ,`a customer can only be associated with a single Payment record through selectedPayment field`.That is why I made it one-to-one.

Are there any pitfalls I haven't anticipated? Please advise.

Comment: There may be some pitfalls in your Entity model. 

Do you not have an Order table or something similar where an Order would then have a mapping to your 'Payment' table? Rather than the Customer table maintaining this 'dynamic' selectedPayment flag? What happens if you have two processes handling a Customer at the same time? It may be I am misunderstanding how this is to be used.

Also I would re-name the Payment table/class to PaymentMethod or something like that. Payment to my mind indicates an Order/Transaction.

Comment: I thought it would be better to keep PaymentMethod as an attribute of Customer.An Order can have a field called customer

Comment: @Dan thanks for suggesting a better name

Comment: That's what I am confused about. If an Order have a Customer field then that Orders' PaymentMethod will 'change' when a subsequent Order is made using a different PaymentMethod (as there is only one Customer Entity)?

Comment: hmm. probably the Order should store the paymentMethod used for that particular buy